# Creating an interactive map in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, interactive

I would like to create an interactive map on my website where you can hover over a location and it will animate showing some links that are clickable and will take the client to another page displaying graphs about that location. What should I learn in order to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You need to learn HTML first. Then CSS for styling.. Next you'll need JavaScript for the client-side logic. Finally, look into the SVG image format, as it dovetails nicely on the web. Lastly, and this is most important, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why did someone downvote? It's a perfectly reasonable question, and well-asked. It's often not possible to google how to achieve something if you're so new that you don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't know much about web development yet, so start with some HTML tutorials (such as [this](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/), or [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/), or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)) and Javascript tutorials (such as [this](https://javascript.info/), or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/), or [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/)). There's a number of ways of creating graphics on web pages ([Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) is a great library that takes all the hard work out of it).

Then you might want to look into learning how the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) works. It's a pretty dang flexible API.